# Applying a patch from java.net

Tags: java, jaxb, hyperjaxb

I have a problem with Jaxb enumerations that is related to this bug

https://jaxb.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=708

A patch has been supplied to the issue that can resolve the problem.
How can I apply this patch to resolve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a source code patch, so it's only useful to you if you're willing to build the JAXB distribution from source. If so:

- Unpack the TAR archive
- Use a diff/patch command line utility, or similar functionality that's build into most source code versioning systems (e.g. in the eclipse SVN plugin right-click project, select Team -> Apply Patch) to apply the patch
- Build the JARs and replace your existing ones with the result.

Comment: @user354414

The patch you're looking at was built on v2.1.12.

So you'll need to be building that at a minimum, what is your current version?

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. Thank is a good starting point. netbeans have a diff tool that I use a lot to compare files(even unversioned ones). Can I use this tool. Or how will I do that via commandline.

thanks

My current jdk is 1.6 update 18. Is that enough?

Comment: @user354414: yes, I think Netbeans has the functionality to apply patches built in. And josek was talking about the JAXB version, not the JDK version.

Comment: @Micheal: Thank you. I dont have a direct jaxb dependency declaration in my pom.xml so I assume it is using the version that came with the JDK that is why I mentioned the jdk version instead

Comment: @Farouk: The JDK does not include the source code, so you'll have to get the standalone JAXB distribution and build on that. And I don't think you can use maven for that kind of thing.

Comment: @Michael: Thank you very much. really appreciated. I feel i should find other peoples problems that I can help. I'm so grateful. Lastly, is it possible to override the jaxb version that comes with Java 1.6.

Kind Regards

Comment: @Farouk: apparently, the standalone distribution uses different package names, so all you have to do is put the JAR in the classpath and change the package names in your code: https://jaxb.dev.java.net/guide/Which_JAXB_RI_is_included_in_which_JDK_.html